# I need to convert Bytes[] to PDF on click and display on the side

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I have a TreeList that I use as a third party DevExpress but I don't need anything related to DevExpress but what when I click there is an event that calls a function in JavaScript that I have PDF bytes in one in the column I would like to know if there is any way to take the bytes and convert it to PDF and show it to the side on the right on the screen, I don't need to download the file or show it on another tab just show it on the right to show a preview of the doc.

I leave some images and my code that currently tells me that the string is too big to pass it through the browser, I wanted to know if someone has done something like this.

[image]
JavaScript Function

```
    function GetPdf(result) {

        alert(result);
        var x = result;
        $("#DisplayPDF").html(
            $('<iframe>', {
                src: 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + x,
                width: '600px',
                height: "800px"
            })
        );
    }
```

View

```
<div id="DisplayPDF" style="float: right; width: 45%;overflow-y:scroll;height:60vh; margin-top:10px"></div>
```

I added an alert of the parameter `result` and that is what I'm getting.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just concatenating the `toString` of `result` to the base64 url, not the base64-encoded value of `result`. Based on the alert, I'm guessing `result` is a Uint8Array. In that case, you can constructor a `Blob` from the binary data, and create a blob URL from it. Then use the blob url to display the pdf. Example:

```js
const bl = new Blob([result], {
    type: "application/pdf"
});
const url = URL.createObjectURL(bl)
$("#DisplayPDF").html(
    $('<iframe>', {
        src: url,
        width: '600px',
        height: "800px"
    })
);
```